# In C++, is it defined behavior to initialize plain arrays with their own first few elements (that are initialized from outer source)?

Tags: c++, arrays, gcc, initialization, simd

In an auto-vectorized array initialization,

```
alignas(64)
const float a[16]={
    b[i+0],b[i+1],b[i+2],b[i+3], // normal initialization

    // self-referencing for duplicated data
    a[0],a[1],a[2],a[3], 
    a[0],a[1],a[2],a[3],
    a[0],a[1],a[2],a[3]
};
```

runs faster than this:

```
alignas(64)
const float a[16]={
    b[i+0],b[i+1],b[i+2],b[i+3], // normal initialization
    b[i+0],b[i+1],b[i+2],b[i+3], // normal initialization
    b[i+0],b[i+1],b[i+2],b[i+3], // normal initialization
    b[i+0],b[i+1],b[i+2],b[i+3], // normal initialization
};
```

Is there any caveat for using the first version? Can it cause any kind of bug for any compiler?

When I try same for transposed version (where columns are duplicated instead), compiler generates same cpu instructions for both versions. Is this a side-effect of compiler's initialization order of elements or is it about ability of CPU architecture (i.e. not having an efficient instruction for that)?

Comment: It's guaranteed to work since C++20. Before C++20, it was under specified, but probably intended to work.

Comment: @eerorika What C++20 change do you consider relevant here?

Comment: @user17732522 Added wording from the designated initialisation proposal: `The initializations of the elements of the aggregate are evaluated in the element order. That is,
all value computations and side effects associated with a given element are sequenced before
those of any element that follows it in order.`

Comment: The other (duplicate answer) says it is "not well defined" but at least it has "defined"? So is it safe to assume element order always goes from 0 to n-1?

Comment: @huseyintugrulbuyukisik Yes, that's the guaranteed element order of arrays.

Comment: @user17732522 In general, an up to date answer would be posted on the target, and one could also leave a comment on the older answer pointing out that it's wrong. You could also ask the answerer to consider updating their answer (although an answer that *was* correct is perfectly fine to have around.) If this question can be made sufficiently different to the target, you can edit it, and add a link to the other question, explaining why it's different, but that doesn't seem viable in this particular case.

Comment: @eerorika I see. I guess I assumed that was the intend of the old evaluation rules as well.

Comment: @user17732522 I added a better duplicate.

Comment: For the performance part, clearly a missed optimization if code ends up compiling to give the same results but slower.

Comment: @eerorika Yeah, that's a better target, with more modern, and better answers. I've closed the original target as a duplicate of that as well. Thanks for finding that.